# Create A PHP Variable Which Changes The Color Of The Background Weekly

Tags: php, css

I would like to create a PHP variable which I can echo to change the color of the background weekly.

Here is what I had reached so far

```
<?php 
    // set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
    date_default_timezone_set('EST');
    $today = date("l");
    if($today == "Sunday") 
        {
            $color = "#FEF0C5";
        }
    elseif($today == "Monday")
        {
            $color = "#FFFFFF";
        } 
    elseif($today == "Tuesday") 
        {
            $color = "#000000";
        } 
    elseif($today == "Wednesday")
        {
            $color = "#FFE0DD";
        } 
    elseif($today == "Thursday")
        {
            $color = "#E6EDFF";
        } 
    elseif($today == "Friday") 
        {
            $color = "#E9FFE6";
        } 
    else 
        {
    // Since it is not any of the days above it must be Saturday
            $color = "#F0F4F1";
        }
    print("<body bgcolor=\"$color\">\n"); 
?>
```

I only managed to make the colors change daily, but i don't know how can I make the colors change weekly instead.

The second thing is that I need to make the colors of each first and last day of the month the color should be pink.

Any help would be very very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to change the color every week:

```
$today = date("W");
```

$today will be a value between 1 and 52, so you'll have every week of the year covered

```
date("t") returns the number of days of the current month
```

So to check if it's the first or last day, you can use this:

```
$LastDayOfMonth = date("Y-m-t");
$FirstDayOfMonth = date("Y-m-01");
```

So to put it all together, you could do it like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
$today = date("W");
switch ($today) {
    case 1:
        $color = "the color you want";
        break;
    case 2:
        $color = "the color you want";
        break;
    case 3:
        $color = "the color you want";
        break;
    // All the other cases here...
}

$CurrentDate = date("Y-m-d");
$LastDayOfMonth = date("Y-m-t");
$FirstDayOfMonth = date("Y-m-1");

if ($CurrentDate == $LastDayOfMonth || $CurrentDate == $FirstDayOfMonth ) {
    $color = "the pink rgb-code";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You saved my day! I got one last question, how can I mark from which case to start from, for example I want this week to start with case 1 .

Answer (score 2):

`date("W")` returns the number of the week inside the year (generally 1-52).

Answer (score 0):

```
$week = date("W");//gives number of week (1-53)
```

then you could use a switch statement to change color for every week

Comment: Better than switching, have an array of colours